# Cópia de Arquivos utilizando biblioteca shutil

Tags: python

Olá,
Estou aprendendo  a progamação em Python e surgiu uma dúvida referente a biblioteca shutil.

Teoricamente, consigo realizar a cópia do arquivo utilizando esta biblioteca, porém, gostaria de saber se há uma forma de ao colar o arquivo em outro diretório, o nome do arquivo seja alterado, adicionando a data do dia atual, de maneira automática, para executar todos os dias.

Para copiar o arquivo para o diretorio de maneira bem rústica, realizo a troca manual no destino, alterando seu nome diretamente no código.

Estou utilizando a seguinte programação:

```
from shutil import copy

orig = r 'diretorio1\arquivo.txt'
des = r 'diretorio2\arquivo_(dia_de_hoje).txt' #aqui realizo o preenchimento manual do dia do hoje, e gostaria que essa parte fosse automática.

copy(orig, des)
```

O resultado que busco é :
arquivo(dia_de_hoje).txt sendo gerado sem eu precisar realizar essa substituição manual no código.

Comment: O que acontece se na variável `des` você definir o novo nome do arquivo? Tipo `des = 'diretorio2/novo.txt'`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. O arquivo é renomeado, porém nesse caso, a substituição é manual.Gostaria de saber se há uma forma de que esse arquivo seja copiado todos os dias so que com a data do dia atual de forma que não seja necessario preencher manualmente a data do dia.

Comment: Use a biblioteca `datetime` para obter a data atual, define o nome do arquivo usando ela e depois configura uma tarefa agendada no seu sistema para executar o código todos os dias.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, amigo. Então, tem uma forma pouco rebuscada de fazer essa transferência de dados + mudança de diretório + alteração do nome do arquivo. Não sei se vai simpatizar, mas vou colocar o código aqui.

### Definindo a data

Há uma forma bem mais rápida de definir a data, utilizando a função datetime(), mas não costumo utilizá-la para ter uma liberdade maior de manipulação do output. Eis como uso:

```
import time
t = time.localtime ()

dia = t.tm_mday
mês = t.tm_mon

if dia < 10:
    dia = str(0) + str(dia) #Acrescentando o 0 em dias menores que 10
if mês < 10:
    mês = str(0) + str(mês) #Acrescentando o 0 em meses menores que 10
    
ano = t.tm_year

data = str(dia) + str(mês) + str(ano)
```

### Arquivo de origem e arquivo de saída

Observe: esta parte do código parte do pressuposto que o arquivo de origem esteja na mesma pasta em que o código está sendo executado. Para mudar isso, basta acrescentar o caminho (path) da pasta, assim como foi feito em "saída".

```
origem = input("Digite o nome do arquivo de origem: ")
arquivo = open(origem + ".txt", "r")
saída = open("/users/HP/" + origem + str(data) + ".txt", "w") #Nome com data. Note que você pode alterar o path para o que deseja. Este "/users/HP/" é apenas um exemplo.
```

### Escrevendo no novo arquivo

```
for linha in arquivo.readlines():
    palavra = linha
    saída.write(palavra)

saída.close()
```

### Código completo

```
import time
t = time.localtime ()

dia = t.tm_mday
mês = t.tm_mon

if dia < 10:
    dia = str(0) + str(dia)
if mês < 10:
    mês = str(0) + str(mês)
    
ano = t.tm_year

data = str(dia) + str(mês) + str(ano)

origem = input("Digite o nome do arquivo de origem: ")
arquivo = open(origem + ".txt", "r")
saída = open("/users/HP/" + origem + str(data) + ".txt", "w")

for linha in arquivo.readlines():
    palavra = linha
    saída.write(palavra)

saída.close()
```

Por fim, basta procurar o novo arquivo no diretório que você escolheu. Espero que tenha conseguido ajudar. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você está tentando implementar um código que seja capaz de copiar um arquivo de um diretório para outro renomeando de modo que o novo nome contenha o nome antigo, mais o carácter de "_", mais a data atual do sistema no modo AAAAMMDD, mais extensão.

**OBSERVAÇÂO:**

A extensão do arquivo é importantíssimo. Pois, o arquivo só poderá ser manipulado, se o mesmo tiver uma extensão válida.

Para implementarmos um código descente devemos prestar atenção na seguinte lógica:

1. Importar as bibliotecas necessárias;
2. Capturar e tratar a data atual;
3. Capturar o caminho de origem do arquivo;
4. Informar o nome completo do arquivo desejado;
5. Capturar o caminho de destino;
6. Copiar e renomear o arquivo.

Pois bem, seguindo esta lógica podemos implementar o seguinte código:

```
from os import chdir, listdir, rename
from shutil import copy
from os.path import isfile
import time

t = time.localtime()
t1, t2, t3 = f'{t[0]}', f'{t[1]:02}', f'{t[2]:02}'

cam = input('Informe o caminho arquivo: ')
chdir(cam)
for i in listdir():
    if isfile(i):
        print(i)
nome = input('Informe o nome completo do arquivo desejado: ')
cam2 = input('Informe o caminho destino: ')
copy(nome, cam2)

chdir(cam2)
for j in listdir():
    if isfile(j) and j == nome:
        rename(nome, nome[:-4] + '_' + t1 + t2 + t3 + nome[-4:])
```

Observe que a primeira coisa no código é a importação das bibliotecas e métodos necessários. Em seguida, é capturada e tratada a data atual. Pois, o método **time.localtime()** nos retorna uma tupla contendo 9 parâmetros, dentre os quis, sevemos nos importar apenas com os três primeiros, que nos fornece, respectivamente, as informações de **ano, mês e dia**. Desse modo temos **t[0] = ano**, **t[1] = mês** e **t[2] = dia**.

Prosseguindo a lógica, o código nos solicitará o caminho do diretório de origem do arquivo. Este caminho, obviamente, é o caminho da pasta que contém o arquivo, o qual desejamos copia-lo.

Depois de informarmos o caminho do arquivo, o código foca no caminho especificado e o primeiro bloco **for** irá percorrer a pasta indicada, listando todos os arquivos da referida pasta.

Nesse momento devemos escolher e informar o nome completo - **nome + extensão** - do arquivo desejado. Posteriormente, devemos informar o caminho do diretório de destino.

Em seguida, o código copia o arquivo na pasta de destino e, depois, o renomeia.